# Password-protected page in AppMaker

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm trying to password protect a page that contains confidential information.

Upon clicking a link, user will be shown a pop-up dialog to enter password.
If successful, redirect user to page. Otherwise, display "Wrong password".

The thing is, this can be easily overcome if user just copies the URL and add "/exec#ConfidentialPage" to the end of the URL.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If at all possible I would highly discourage implementing your own authentication system and instead rely on Google login to secure your data. See https://developers.google.com/appmaker/security/secure-your-app. My short recommendation is to:

- Create a google group which contains the users you want to access the
  data.
- Create a role in App Maker which contains that group
- Restrict access to both your data and your view to members of that role.

This is much more secure than a password based approach as #1 It's implemented by Google (implementing your own auth correctly is *hard*) and #2 You have a list of everyone who has access to your data in the form of the Google group.

Comment: Thanks Devin for the reply. You're right. I guess I'll use the security permissions from google.